# Swift Data crashes on model array interaction

Tags: swift, swift-data

I am having trouble with a very basic swift data implementation.
I have a couple of nested models, each of them containing a list of another model. For demo purposes I have removed all other variables, since they don't seem to cause any trouble.

Example:

```swift
    @Model
    class Routine {
        
        @Relationship var exercises: [Exercise]
        
        init() {
            self.exercises = [Exercise(sets: [Set(reps: 0)])]
        }
        
        func getRep() -> Int {
            return self.exercises[0].sets[0].reps
        }
        
        func increase() {
            self.exercises[0].sets[0].reps += 1
        }
    }

    @Model
    class Exercise {
        
        @Relationship var sets: [Set]
        
        init(sets: [Set]) {
            self.sets = sets
        }
    }

    @Model
    class Set {
        
        @Relationship var reps: Int
        
        init(reps: Int) {
            self.reps = reps
        }
    }
```

Whenever I touch the exercise Array the app crashes without an error log. As a proof of concept, I tried a very basic demo with a button. Once a user presses the button, the number of the nested object should change, and be seen on the screen.
However, the app crashes on startup. I assume it's because I set the exercise field in the Routine constructor (without that field it works).

Also, here's the View / WindowGroup code of my example:

```swift
@main
struct SwiftDataDemoApp: App {
   
    let container: ModelContainer
    
    init() {
        do {
            container = try ModelContainer(for: Routine.self, Exercise.self, Set.self)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to create model container")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(container)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {

    var routine = Routine()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Reps: \(routine.getRep())")
            
            Button(action: routine.increase) {
                Text("Increase!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far I have tried:

- Adding deleteRule and/or inverse to the @Relationship
- adding all models into the container

both without any success.

Comment: `self.exercises = [Exercise(sets: [Set(reps: 0)])]`, don’t do this. Try the simpler `self.exercises = []` and see if that works without crashing.

Comment: It always crashes on the first interaction with the array. So starting it like that works, but if I have a button that adds an exercise, it crashes

Comment: I encountered the similar issue yesterday. My understanding is that the relational values must exist in the database.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your code.

First of all you should always define properties for both ends of the relationship. So if you have the property `var exercises: [Exercise]` you should also have the opposite end, `var routine: Routine?`.

I made the to-one side of the relationship optional since I feel it simplifies the creation of objects.

Then you should only use the init for setting local properties and relationships so don't do

```
self.exercises = [Exercise(sets: [Set(reps: 0)])]
```

So with those modifications the model definitions become (the `name` property was only added for testing)

```
@Model
class Routine {
    var name: String
    @Relationship var exercises: [Exercise]

    init(name: String, exercises: [Exercise]) {
        self.name = name
        self.exercises = exercises
    }
}

@Model
class Exercise {
    var name: String
    var routine: Routine?
    @Relationship var sets: [ExerciseSet]

    init(name: String, sets: [ExerciseSet], routine: Routine? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.sets = sets
        self.routine = routine
    }
}

@Model
class ExerciseSet {
    var exercise: Exercise?
    var reps: Int

    init(reps: Int, exercise: Exercise? = nil) {
        self.reps = reps
        self.exercise = exercise
    }
}
```

Note also that `reps` in `ExerciseSet` (that I renamed because I prefer not to use name already used by any built-in type) is not a relationship property but an ordinary stored one.

Finally here is an example of creating instances and connecting them

```
let set1 = ExerciseSet(reps: 5)
let set2 = ExerciseSet(reps: 10)
let exercise = Exercise(name: "Exercise 1", sets: [set1, set2])

let routine = Routine(name: "Routine \(Date().formatted(date: .omitted, time: .standard))", exercises: [exercise])
modelContext.insert(routine)
```

Comment: Sadly still crashes when I create the Routine object.

Comment: This code is properly tested so I know it should work. Perhaps try this code in a new separate project?